# Controller this.control() method extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a toolbar named **DasboardToolbar** in which i have a splitbutton.
The problem when I click a **menuitem** in the splitbutton it fires a event which the controller's **this.control** method should catch but it doesn't. The object used for firing event is the object of the component still its responding to the fired event.
Any help appreciated.

**The is the controller i'm using**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MainController',
            {
                extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

                views : [ 'header.MSHeader', 'dashboard.toolbar.DashboardToolbar',
                      ],

                init : function() {
                    console.log("controller");
                    this.control({
                        'MSHeader' : {
                            tabChanged : this.tabChangeTracker
                        }
                    }, {
                        'dash.DashToolbar' : {
                            layoutSelected :this.layoutSelectedTracker, //errorstatment

                        }
                    });

                },
               layoutSelectedTracker:function(){
console.log('catched'); // code never reaches here
    }

    });
```

**The Component**

```
 Ext.define('MyApp.view.dashboard.toolbar.DashboardToolbar', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.dash.DashToolbar',
    id : 'dashtoolbar',

    initComponent : function() {
        var me = this;
        this.items = [ {
            xtype : 'toolbar',
            items : [  {
                xtype : 'splitbutton',
                width : '55',
                text : 'layout',
                autoScroll : true,
                menu : new Ext.menu.Menu({
                    id : 'layoutmenu',
                    items : [

                    {
                        xtype : 'button',
                        text : 'First',

                        handler : function() {
                            me.fireEvent("layoutSelected", { //eventFired from here
                                layouts : 1
                            });

                        }

                    }]
                })

            } ]
        } ], 
               this.callParent();
    }

});
```

Comment: Don't use `.` in the alias. Change it to `widget.dash_DashToolbar`.

Comment: Also, why on earth would you set autoScroll on a button?!?!

Comment: widget.dash_DashToolbar din't worked :(
@EvanTrimboli I would be dynamically adding menu items in splitbutton in future keeping it height fixed therefore a autoScroll option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the id of the component?

```
this.control({
    'MSHeader': {
        tabChanged: this.tabChangeTracker
    },
    '#dashtoolbar': {
        layoutSelected: this.layoutSelectedTracker
    }
});
```

`this.control` uses `Ext.ComponentQuery`, have a look at the documentation there.

Comment: Yes,I even have tried this approach.
MSHeard works perfectly using xtype but the same approach fails with xtype of DashboardToolbar

Comment: So you tried using the id and that doesn't work? Or did it work and you want to use the xtype?

Comment: Please correct your code, there is an extra `},` that shouldn't be there.

Please compare with my `this.control`

Comment: Yes, even i noticed the extra } but that's not the actual problem

Comment: I think it is, please see this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2r0 with a working example of your components.

Comment: Yes, it finally worked :)
There was some issue with braces. 
No Intellisense :(
Thanks :)